# EXCEL Find values containing

Tags: excel, vlookup

I have a list of product codes and product SKUs and need to find partial matches. The problem is all the data is out of order.

I have provided a subset of data done manually

```
Master SKU  Product Code Corresponding Product SKU
1_100049    1000510     1_1000510
1_1000510   1000511     1_1000511
1_1000511   100052      4_100052
1_100052    1000525     N/A
1_100053    100053      2_100053
1_100054    100054      1_100054
1_1000560   1000540     N/A
1_1000570   100055      N/A
1_1000575   1000560     1_1000560
1_100060    1000570     1_1000570
1_1000600   1000575     6_1000575
1_100061    100060      3_100060
1_1000620   1000600     1_1000600
```

I need to find the Product SKU corresponding to the product code. Is there anyway to just list the match in column C? (The data is just in in two columns A and B)

The formula I have is

```
=VLOOKUP(A2,B$2:B$6000,3,"TRUE")
```

Comment: Is Product code is always a substring of Product sku?

Comment: Yes, unless there is not matching SKU. More data provided

Answer (score 0):

This `VLOOKUP` may work for you.  Adjust the lookup range to your data:

```
  =VLOOKUP(RIGHT(A2,LEN(A2)-2),$B$2:$B$2,1,0)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use INDEX/MATCH on a modified Master-SKU column with an array formula

```
=INDEX(A2:A10,MATCH(B2,RIGHT(A2:A10,LEN(B2)),0))
```

Use Ctrl-Shift-Enter when you insert the formula. If your columns contain numbers instead of text, you might have to add VALUE

```
=INDEX(A2:A10,MATCH(B2,VALUE(RIGHT(A2:A10,LEN(B2))),0))
```